# Is it true that $\exists X \succeq 0, AXB \succeq 0 \implies \exists Y \succ 0, AYB \succ 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-matrix-inequality

Consider the rectangular matrices $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$. Is it true that, if there exists a square and positive semi-definite matrix $X \succeq 0$ such that $AXB \succeq 0$, then there exists a square and positive definite matrix $Y \succ 0$ such that $AYB \succ 0$?

Here is my initial attempt at proving this: given $X \succeq 0$ such that $AXB \succeq 0$, this implies that, for every $z \in \mathbb R^m$, $z^TAXBz \geq 0$. Because $X \succeq 0$, then its square root $X^{1/2}$ exists, such that $z^TAXBz = z^TAX^{1/2}X^{1/2}Bz = x^Ty \geq 0$, where $x = X^{1/2}A^Tz$ and $y = X^{1/2}Bz$. However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here, so would appreciate any guidance. My next guess would be to let $Y = X + \varepsilon I \succ 0$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Counterexample $A$ (or $B$) $=0$.

Comment: @AnneBauval good catch. Thanks. Do you think the restriction that there exists a non-zero $X \succeq 0$ such that $AXB \succeq 0$, where $A$ and $B$ are both non-zero, is enough to salvage this proof? Or is there another counter example that you have even with this restriction?

Comment: Consider the case where $A$ and $B^T$ are square matrices with identical first columns $v$. Then $AE_{11}B=vv^T\succeq0$. However, when $\det(AB)<0$, there does not exist any $Y\succ0$ such that $AYB\succ0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conjecture is unreasonable because the special case $m=n,A=X=I_n$ would imply $$
B\succeq 0\implies(\exists Y\succ 0\quad YB\succ 0)\implies\det B\ne0.$$